# proxy nodejs express at package.json raised an error on campus network

Tags: node.js, express

I work on a project as a fullstack developer on using reactjs & express.

My express server is on server folder, and reactjs client is on server/client.

I set the following proxy at my package.json at my server/client folder which includes ReactJS (create-react-app based). :

```
 "private": true,
  "proxy": {
    "auth/google": {
      "target": "http://localhost:5000"
    },
    "/api/*": {
      "target": "http://localhost:5000"
    },
    "/apis/*": {
      "target": "http://localhost:5000"
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
```

When I connect to interent at the university campus I get the following error 
[image]
but when I connect to internet outside campus no error happens. How can I avoid that from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really appreciate your help guys. I found that the issue is not related to university network restrictions. I found the main problem, is that express server is not working on the university network, so
`npm run server` which is `"server": "nodemon index.js",`
cause an error:
[image]

and that what searching for its solution now. You may help me on finding that even by linking to other posts resources.